# Select parent and child records and sort by child using rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, parent

I'm trying to show a list of all Tasks (including the associated project info for each) for a user on their 'show' page.

```
User has_many projects
Project belongs_to user
Project has_many tasks
Task belongs_to project
```

I want a list of all tasks for the user, with separate rows for each task even if they both relate to a single project. I will need to display the project name in the row as well as task name.

Eg

```
**Tasks for User 1**
Project 1  |  Task 1
Project 2  |  Task 2
Project 3  |  Task 3
Project 1  |  Task 4
Project 3  |  Task 5
Project 3  |  Task 6
Project 2  |  Task 7
```

Can anyone suggest how this with Rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways. One uses a join:

```
@tasks = @user.tasks.joins(:projects).order("projects.id")
```

To make this work a user must have many tasks

```
has_many :tasks, through: :projects
```

The other method uses eager loading:

```
@projects = @user.projects.includes(:tasks)
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm after. Can you give an example of outputting it in a view - ie referring to columns from both the projects and the tasks tables

Comment: something to the effect of `@tasks.each{ |t| [t.name, t.project.name].join("-") }`

Comment: That's what I was after but I think your code should've been `@tasks.each do |t| { [t.name, t.project.name].join("-") }`

Answer (score 0):

```
# controller
@projects = current_user.projects.joins(:tasks)

# view
-@projects.each do |project|
  -project.tasks.each do |task|
    %p
      =project.title
      |
      =task.title
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm after because it loops through the projects and then the tasks. I think I worded my question wrong...sorry. I need to loop through the tasks and output project info for each as required so it may display a task for a project and then tasks for other projects and show a task for this project again further down the list (not necessarily together).